# Is this enough to show that an improper integral diverges?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

We know that if $f:(a, b)\to \mathbb{R}$ ($-\infty\le a < b \le \infty$) is a locally Riemann integrable function, then the improper integral $\displaystyle \int_a^b f(x)dx$ is said to be convergent if there is some $c\in (a, b)$ such that $\displaystyle \int_a^c f(x)dx$ and $\displaystyle \int_c^bf(x) dx$ are both convergent.

Now, a comment made by my lecturer after this definition said that this definition doesn't depend on $c$.
Does this mean that if I find a $c\in (a, b)$ such that one of $\displaystyle \int_a^c f(x)dx$ and $\displaystyle \int_c^bf(x)dx$ diverges then I may say that $\displaystyle \int_a^b f(x) dx$ diverges?

I think that it does, but I am not really sure. I tried going for a contradiction, but I got stuck.

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: The catch is that one or both of the smaller integral expressions could also be improper. For a specific function, it could take a particular $c$ to make it easy to show divergence.

Comment: @aschepler so basically I am correct, right?

Comment: Well, your statement is true but not a strict consequence of the first definition. It's a strange sort of recursive definition anyway.

Comment: @aschepler ah, sure, I just included the first definition to be sure that everyone is on the same page